# How to selecting the row index of HTML table by search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find the index of a HTML table row that contains a given ID, the ID is in a known column (the last column). It needs to check if the table has that ID and then ultimately delete the row - I've come up with the following to find the index but I always get an index of -1

```
var index = $('#myTable td:contains(' + ID + ')').index($(this));
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Add please your html code.

Comment: What is the value of `this`?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the index to remove a row. You can use the `:contains` selector to find the `td` then simply call `remove()` on the parent `tr` element:

```
$('#myTable td:contains("' + ID + '")').closest('tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the TR element from your searched TD. You can step backward one step by issuing the closest() method.

So, you can find the index of the row the following way. Remember, index starts at 0:

```
var index = $('#myTable td:contains(' + ID + ')').closest("tr").index();
```

You can directly remove the TR also with the following line of code. This will remove all rows that contains ID in any cell:

```
$('#myTable td:contains(' + ID + ')').closest("tr").remove();
```